# finding href value in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, lxml

i'm working on project ,that searches the webpage content for some data

```
  from lxml import html 
  import requests

  def tabletPhone(webAddress):
            page = requests.get(webAddress)
            tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
            product = tree.xpath("""//h1[@class="product_title entry-\
    title"]/text()""")
            price = tree.xpath("""//span[@class='price-number']/text()""")
            availability = tree.xpath("//n:link",namespaces={'n':'availability'})

            return product,price,availability
```

I have problem with finding availability of product , html code is somthing like :

```
<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />
```

Is any way to return {'availability':'http://schema.org/InStock'} or return 'http://schema.org/InStock'

Comment: Does that node belong to a different namespace? Have you tried `availability = tree.xpath("//link[@itemprop='availability' and @href]/@href")`?

Answer (score 1):

Using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).We can achieve this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
samplecode = '''<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a> <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/> <link itemprop="availability" href="http://google.com"/>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(samplecode,"lxml")
for line in soup.find_all(href=True):
    print "Url-", line['href']
```

Above Code Snippet will work for all tags.it will search for href in all tags but if you want to search for a specific tag then use as follows:

```
for line in soup.find_all('link',href=True):
    print "Url-", line['href']
```